# Проблема установки fuzzywuzzy

Tags: python, python-3.x, установка

Попытался установить fuzzywuzzy c помощью `pip install fuzzywuzzy` но вышла ошибка
`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fuzzywuzzy (from versions:)
No matching distribution found for fuzzywuzzy` Где найти и как установить рабочую версию fuzzywuzzy?

Comment: Попробуй установить так:
pip install git+git://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy.git@0.18.0#egg=fuzzywuzzy

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось! Но вышла такая ошибка: `Using slow pure-python SequenceMatcher. Install python-Levenshtein to remove this warning` я закоментировал её в скрипте fuzz.py  и всё заработало